# Has anyone been able to access the video transcription feature in Google Cloud's Video Intelligence API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, video-intelligence-api

1. [This four-month-old press release](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/12/cloud-video-intelligence-and-cloud-natural-language-content-classification-are-now-generally-available) seems to indicate that the feature is publicly available,
2. [The product page](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/) mentions the feature, but labels it in an alpha state, and
3. [The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/reference/rest/v1/videos/annotate#Feature) doesn't mention the feature at all...

Anyone have any leads on how to try this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [press release](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/12/cloud-video-intelligence-and-cloud-natural-language-content-classification-are-now-generally-available) you linked does not indicate that the feature is publicly available:

> Today, we’re releasing video transcription in private beta...You can apply for the private beta by contacting your account manager.